# Insertion of an attribute of an attribute in a knowledge-graph with grakn / graql

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql, knowledge-graph

My KG contains instances of a relation type that has an attribute.

I would like to insert new attribute values, but now linked to the attribute that already exists in those relations (attributes of an attribute).

Considering a fictional example, first I would insert the relation:

```
match
$per isa person, has id_per "xyz123";
$pro isa product, has id_pro "abc123";
insert $pur (purchaser: $per, purchased: pro) isa purchase, has invoice "aei379";
```

And after that, suppose that I want to insert a new attribute, `invoice-date "2020-06-14"` as an attribute of `invoice "aei379"`.

How should I write the query for the match of the attribute `invoice "aei379"` and the insert of the new attribute `invoice-date "2020-06-14"`?

Is it necessary to match an specific relation (in my example there can be more than one relation with the same attribute) or is it possible to match directly the `invoice` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an attribute to another attribute like that:

```
match 
$n "aei379" isa invoice;
insert 
$n, has invoice-date "2020-06-14";
```

or you can do it in one query

```
match
$per isa person, has id_per "xyz123";
$pro isa product, has id_pro "abc123";
insert 
$a "aei379";
$a isa invoice, has invoice-date "2020-06-14";
$pur (purchaser: $per, purchased: pro) isa purchase, has invoice $a;
```

Comment: @Jorge no problem